# Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed trying to catkin_make glog_catkin

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Community,

I am currently trying to get the ROS_quadrotor_simulator from Wil Selby running on my machine.
I am following the wiki from his github (https://github.com/wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator).

When i try to run catkin make after I got the glog_catkin and catkin_simple package i get the following error:

Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed

I am running all this on Ubuntu 18.04 and the ROS melodic distro.

I appreciate any help on that. Thanks alot!

Update - thats the full error i get:

```
####
#### Running command: "make -j12 -l12" in "/home/thorsten/test_ws/build"
####
[ 12%] Performing patch step for 'glog_src'
/bin/sh: 1: cannot open /home/thorsten/test_ws/src/fix-unused-typedef-warning.patch: No such file
glog_catkin/CMakeFiles/glog_src.dir/build.make:101: recipe for target 'glog_catkin/glog_src-prefix/src/glog_src-stamp/glog_src-patch' failed
make[2]: *** [glog_catkin/glog_src-prefix/src/glog_src-stamp/glog_src-patch] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:481: recipe for target 'glog_catkin/CMakeFiles/glog_src.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [glog_catkin/CMakeFiles/glog_src.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314472/invoking-%22make--j12--l12%22-failed-trying-to-catkin_make-glog_catkin/) by [cluue](https://answers.ros.org/users/39748/cluue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-02-01**:
Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the full error?

**Comment by [cluue](https://answers.ros.org/users/39748/cluue/) on 2019-02-01**:
I updated the question @jayess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been [reported upstream](https://github.com/ethz-asl/glog_catkin/issues/27), but so far no fix has been commited.

However, the solution is also shown in the issue:

> The first problem is that in line 15 `PATCH_COMMAND patch -p0 < ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fix-unused-typedef-warning.patch` the directory to find `fix-unused-typedef-warning.patch` is set to `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`, which is `~/test_ws/src/` [in your case], but the file is in `~/catkin_ws/src/glog_catkin/` in your case]. So you should change `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cluue](https://answers.ros.org/users/39748/cluue/) on 2019-02-01**:
Great, I changed it in the CMakeList of the glog_catkin package and it worked!
Thanks alot!